# Mann Whitney u test on large data-sets gives error in python

Tags: scipy, python-3.5

I want to run Mann whitney U test on two list of 10,000 and 100,000 numbers. Using python I can run the test using scipy.stats:

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
mann_u=mannwhitneyu([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
```

without anyproblem. But when I use this code on large data, it returns the following error:

```
from random import randint
x=[randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
y=[randint(0,9) for p in range(0,100000)]
mannwhitneyu(x,y)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:4630: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
sd = np.sqrt(T * n1 * n2 * (n1+n2+1) / 12.0)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1748:  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x > self.a) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1748: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x > self.a) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1749: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
Out[66]: MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=4995054086.5, pvalue=nan)
```

Any suggestions what is going on in here?

Comment: Do you have missing values?

Comment: what is 'missing value'?! They are two simple lists of numbers.

Comment: The error suggests that there is an invalid value in the function `np.sqrt(T * n1 * n2 * (n1+n2+1) / 12.0)` n1 and n2 are the number of observations so they are not the problem. T is the sum of the ranks. That cannot be negative so there might be [missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data)/null/non-number values in your lists. They are represented as `nan` in numpy/scipy.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be the problem. I edited the question. It doesnt work even on random lists.

Comment: I tried it on both Python 3.5 / scipy 0.18.0 and Python 2.7 / scipy 0.17.0. It works fine. Can you try updating your scipy?

Comment: @user3015703 Which version of scipy are you using?  You can find out with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: I am using Anacoda 4.1.1 (python 3.5) in windows with scipy version: 0.17.1. Actually now that I tried it on linux (python 3.5) with scipy 0.16.0 ,it worked!!!! Thank you for hint